# Maven wont pick up Spock tests

Tags: maven, groovy, spock, gmaven-plugin, groovy-eclipse

I've been trying to set up *Maven* to run my *Spock* (0.7) tests but to no avail.  I've been trying to use `groovy-eclipse-compiler` as `gmaven` which is refered to in the *Spock* documentation is no longer recommended according to its' website.  The relevant section of my *POM*:

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.0-01</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.8-01</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

When I run `mvn test` I get:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Any ideas why *maven/surefire* just isn't picking up my tests? As the section of the website suggests I've ensured there is a blank file present in `src/test/java`

Comment: How did you resolve your problem?

Comment: As Peter suggested below, I set up surefire to detect the tests with he correct naming pattern.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Surefire will pick up Spock tests automatically as long as the test classes match Surefire's naming conventions (`*Test` etc. by default). First you should check if the test classes actually get compiled and are present under `target/test-classes`. If not, there is probably something wrong with how you set up the Groovy compiler.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an IDE like Idea or Eclipse, it may happen that building the project from the IDE successfully compiles your test classes.

1. To ensure that a maven build is working and properly configured issue a `mvn clean verify` from the command line.
2. Check if the build compiled the test classes at `target/test-classes`

If the test classes were not compiled, then the problem is a misconfiguration of the `gmavenplus-plugin` responsible for compiling the groovy code.

More than probable, you are missing the execution goals part:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
  <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.4</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal>
        <goal>testCompile</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```